# ¿Porque cada vez que se llena mi historial, después de un tiempo debo de borrarlo para que se apliquen los cambios de CSS?

Tags: php, mysql, css, apache, google-chrome

El problema es que cuando estoy trabajando orientado a la web, mas precisamente en php y a través de las herramientas de XAMPP lo que viene siendo servidor apache y mysql, durante un tiempo va todo bien, pero después de que haya visitado muchas paginas o mejor dicho haya navegado un buen tiempo claro que mi historial se llena tanto de cockies como de elementos alternos y pues me he dado cuenta de que hago cambios en mis paginas webs pero no se ven y son cambios sencillos, sobre todo en css, como el cambio de color, de letra etc. y después borro mi historial y acepta los cambios de manera automática.

Trabajo a través del navegador Chrome y Opera pero en ambos, pasa pero mas en Chrome

De casualidad  saben a que se debe este error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es ningún error, así funcionan los navegadores para cargar mas rápido las paginas.

Lo que puedes hacer es deshabilitar la cache:

1. En **Chrome**:

   - Presiona **F12**
   - Ve a la solapa **Network**
   - Selecciona el check **Disable Cache**
2. En **Firefox**:

   - Presiona **F12**
   - Ve a **opciones de la barra de herramientas**
   - En **Ajustes avanzados** selecciona el check **Desactivar Cache**

en opera creo que es muy similar a firefox, aunque debes mantener abierta la consola(F12) para que no guarde la cache y los cambios sean visibles de inmediato en el refresh

Comment: Solo para tener en cuenta, el método que explicas para Chrome desactiva la caché únicamente cuando la ventana de DevTools está abierta.

Answer (score 2):

Esto se debe a la **cache del navegador** y no al historial de navegación de nuestro navegador.

El **caché del navegador** es un lugar de almacenamiento temporal que se encuentra en la computadora y que guarda archivos que han sido descargados por el navegador para mostrar sitios. Dentro de estos archivos se encuentran aquellos documentos necesarios para la visualización de un sitio como archivos html, hojas de estilo de CSS, scripts de JavaScript, gráficos, imágenes y contenido multimedia en general.

Cuando se vuelve a visitar un sitio, el navegador chequea qué contenido ha sido actualizado desde la fecha de la última visita y sólo descarga los archivos nuevos o lo que ya no esté guardado en el caché. Lo que hace esto es reducir el uso del ancho de banda tanto en el usuario como en el servidor, lo que permite que el sitio se cargue más rápido. Por eso el caché es especialmente útil cuando el usuario tiene una conexión lenta.

Es por eso, que a veces no se suelen presenciar de manera rápida algunos cambios hechos, incluso aunque sean mínimos.

Para la otra solo borra el cache del navegador, presiona F5 y verás que rápido cambia todo :P

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Esto se debe al cacheo del navegador . Para resolver esta situacion , lo que deberias hacer es agregarle un versionado a tu archivo de estilos o cualquier otro que tengas.

Ejemplo .

podrias agregarle una variable con dato dinamico cada vez que cargues tu pagina y te olvidas del cacheo .

suerte.

Answer (score 0):

Esto no responde a la pregunta directamente, pero puedes usar un cachebuster en tus archivos de estilos o de javaScript para evitar ese problema:

```
<?php $buster = $rand(0, 9999999); ?>

<link type="text/css" href="estilo.css?v=<?php echo $buster=>">

<script src="scripts.js?v=<?php echo $buster?>"></script>
```

En caso que no funcione deberías revisar la configuración de tus navegadores o tal vez tu proveedor de internet o el modem tenga algún parámetro de caché.