# Problema al modificar css

Tags: php, css

Al querrer modificar el css no realiza los cambios que yo hago ... aunque elimine una linea del css es como que siempre esta y no entiendo el porque ... aunque los archivos son php habria un problema?

Comment: Esta [repuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/20743/12864) puede ayudarle. quizá solucione su problema.

Comment: eso tambien serviria si por ejemplo el archivo es php pero dentro tengo código php y html y quiero agregar un input pero no muestra el cambio seria igual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En chrome y firefox puedes forzar el navegador a recargar los estilos css:

```
ctr+Shift+R
```

Comment: muchas gracias tu respuesta me sirvio

Answer (score 1):

El problema, a veces, es que el navegador te cachea el css, el js y las imágenes. Por ende, una buena solución (recomendada para desarrollo más que para el entorno productivo) es poner lo siguiente en la llamada al script/s de css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mi.css?uuid=<?php echo uniqid();?>">
```

O sea, generás el llamado con un query string que vaya variando en cada petición (en este caso, con la función uniqid).

Con eso, te asegurás de que el navegador no cachee nunca el css, ya que lo interpreta siempre como una "petición distinta".

Asegurate de sacarlo cuando lo vayas a deployar en producción, a menos que quieras que en producción tampoco lo cachee.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

No afecta que sea un archivo php. Tene en cuenta que si el elemento al que le estás modificando el css está dentro de otro, el css del elemento padre puede afectar al elemento en el cual queres cambiar el css. 
Te recomiendo usar el debugger del FireFox o si estás trabajando con Chrome usa ese, proba modificar el css en el debugger.

Comment: probe eso pero digamos al volver a iniciar sesión en el archivo la página no guardo los cambios